# pass arraylist from asynctask to the method calling it android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am having a scenario in which I am calling  asynctask in onclicklistener of button. In post execute method of asynctask I am adding values in arraylist which I want to return to the method calling asynctask

This is my asynctask

```
 public class FetchtopTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 try {


                     String getitemcode=params[0];
                        // Building Parameters
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                       params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ItemCode",getitemcode));
                        Log.d("request!", "starting");
                        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/top.php",params1);


                        String retstring=response.toString();
                        Log.d(retstring,"stringggggg");
                        return retstring;
                    }
                 catch(Exception io){
                 msg = "No Network Connection";
                 }
                 return null;
           }


             @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {
                          try {
                                    JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);


                                    for(int i=0;i<aJson.length();i++)
                                    {
                                         JSONObject jsonO = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                                         top1.add(jsonO.getString("MName"));
                                         top2.add(jsonO.getString("Amount"));
                                         top3.add(jsonO.getString("TaxStruct"));

                               }

                          }catch(JSONException e){
                               msg = "Invalid response";
                           }
                        }

     }
```

I want to pass top1,top2,top3 arraylists to calling method
please help me to achieve this.

Comment: where you want to return it?? declare your arraylist globally what is the problem can you explicate it properly?

Comment: I want to return the arraylist to the method which is calling  the  asynctask, it is button onclicklistener.

Answer (score 1):

You may use ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tops= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

tops.add(top1);
tops.add(top2);
tops.add(top3);
```

and

```
return tops;
```

Comment: how should I return arraylist from postexecute method ??

Comment: return means not actual return because onPostExecute does not return anything  you can use handler or for simplest way you can call another function with this param.Do research more on AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

hey Just call AsyncTask in btn Click 
and in post execute method
call another method which will use that Array which is created in post Execute.

```
@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {
                      try {
                                JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);
                                for(int i=0;i<aJson.length();i++)
                                {
                                     JSONObject jsonO = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                                     top1.add(jsonO.getString("MName"));
                                     top2.add(jsonO.getString("Amount"));
                                     top3.add(jsonO.getString("TaxStruct"));

                                     anotherMethod(top);
                           }
                      }catch(JSONException e){
                           msg = "Invalid response";
                       }
                    }
```

Comment: I want to use this arraylist in the buttonclicklistener which is calling the asynctask

Comment: you cant do that because in btn click listner ArrayList will null because asynctask is just like thread. so you want to use arraylist then  you should use second method in post execute for performing action on array list data.

Comment: second method in post execute means?